# Wordpress Divi back to post archive with specific category link

Tags: php, wordpress, divi

How does one create a button to link back to the post archive page, from a specific post article, with a specific category selected?
e.g. /category/partners/   (partners being a category posts can belong to)

Situation: DiviTheme theme - Theme Builder - Custom Body on 'All Posts'

I've created a 'button' module. This button has a 'text' option which allows the dynamic selection of a category. (the category the post belongs to) - Tick: This displays fine.
The issue is the link on this button is empty.

[image: Divi button settings]

Now, I can see the issue that if the post belongs to more categories which do you link to...
But "HOW" can one create a link within each post to link back to the post archive FILTERING only by the category that the post belongs to (similar concept to 'show other posts within this category') - Assuming that a post belongs to only 1 category.

I can create a short code but it seems like such a hack...

Is there a way to do this within Divi and it's standard framework of modules?